# Rally-app-builder displays nothing in browser for "Story Board" app

Tags: javascript, rally

I have been attempting to learn how to build a Rally app using the rally-app-builder.  I began wiith the Your first Rally app tutorial at  https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/guide/first_app, after following the instructions for installing Node.js, and the rally-app-builder, I got to the step where we are supposed to add a rallycombobox to our app.  However, when I run the App-debug.html file, my screen is blank.  I have attempted to add other objects rather than a combobox and still nothing appears on the screen in the browser.  I noticed that one other person had asked this question several months ago, but there is no answer posted as to why this might happen.  I attempted to view the App-debug.html file in several browsers as well.  None of them displayed the expected output.

Here is the code for the app.js file.

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    launch: function () {
        this.iterationCombobox = this.add({
            xtype: 'rallyiterationcombobox',
            listeners: {
                ready: this._onIterationComboboxLoad,
                scope: this
            }
        });
    },
});
```

Comment: 2.0rc3 is the latest release of the appsdk- is it possible to use that?  are there any errors in the console?

Comment: I don't get any errors in the console and I am using 2.0rc3.  The link is for a tutorial that must have been done when 2.0rc1 was still the most current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I use the exact code you posted I get this error in the console of Chrome's DevTools:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
```

The reason for it is that in this code `_onIterationComboboxLoad` is called but never defined.
Try an alternative browser and check javascript console for errors.

To fix the error you may add this method after `launch` :

```
_onIterationComboboxLoad:function(){
//can be empty for now
}
```

As far as general steps to use rally app builder, try this:

Assuming rally app builder is installed, a command `rab --version`  should return a version, e.g. 0.9.2

In the terminal, cd to a directory that you created for a Story Board app.
Run this command:

```
rab init "Story Board" 2.0rc3
```

You should see this output:

```
Creating a new App named Story Board
Creating App-debug.html
Creating App.html
Creating App-uncompressed.html
Success
```

Look at the code that the rally-app-builder (rab) generated:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    items:{ html:'<a href="https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/">App SDK 2.0rc3 Docs</a>'},
    launch: function() {
        //Write app code here
    }
})
```

Open App-debug.html in a browser. 
There should be a link to AppSDK2rc3 documentation on top of an otherwise empty page. This link indicates that the app is working.

Assuming it works, you may delete the content of App.js file generated by rab and replace it with the entire code example from the Building Your First App guide [here](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/guide/first_app). Copy the entire code of App.js under "The finished app should look like this" and test it in the browser to make sure it works. After that you may delete the content of App.js file once again and go back to the guide and follow it step by step, knowing what to expect.

If at any point you get an empty page, check the console in Dev Tools of your browser and also try alternative browsers. If you are not currently logged in to Rally in another tab of the same browser you will be prompted to login when loading App-debug.html.

Comment: Thanks nickm, the app seems to work now.  I think there may have been an authentication problem with Rally.  When I posted this question I was working from home through a VPN.  Now I'm at my desk wired in to the business network and things seem to be fine.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things that I have learned with this problem and I had a lot of issues with finding information on the blank Story Board page.

One is that you should be using an API key in the URL string that is defined at the Rally instance that you are trying to access. Without that, you will be faced with errors that show up in the Development tools as no "Access-Control-Allow-Header" errors and a blank screen. So the process would be developing with rally-app-builder that you run the web instance locally with `rally-app-builder -run` then in the URL when the web browser opens add a `?apiKey="Your api key"` then refresh the browser.